# Changing the value of a 2d array every x turns?

Tags: java, coordinates

Im creating an 'Avoid the Blocks' game, and for this i need to move a character around a grid (2D array) using the keys GHKJ. Every x amount of turns (decreasing as the level increases) a shadow must appear, then that shadow becomes a block and if the player moves into that bloack they lose a life. 
Most of this is done for me other than the seemingly simple taski of getting the blocks to appear, here is my code so far for the falling blocks:

```
public void rocked(){
int rockInit = turn;        
    if(rockInit > 1){
        int save = turn;
        System.out.println(turn + " ");
        B.board[ran.nextInt(12)][ran.nextInt(12)] = shadow;
            if(save == turn - 3){
                B.board[rockLocX][rockLocY] = rock;
        } 
    } 
}
```

The system.println is simply for debugging purposes, checking the values are being accesed. Turn is increased by 1 for every move the player makes, ran.nextInt(12) is a randomly generated number between 0 and 11, and B.board is the playing board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're never changing "save" after you initialize it to "turn". So then when you check if(save == turn-3), it will always be false, and so never move the block in. If you want to keep track of how many turns have passed, I would recommend a private instance variable "int turnsPassed" that you can increment each turn. Then for each level, you can check if (turnsPassed % x == 0), where x is as you've described it. Hope that helps!